# Increment CSS property values in Safari web inspector with keyboard arrows

Tags: safari, web-inspector

In Safari's web inspector tools, when modifying a CSS property of an element, is there a way to increment with the keyboard's up and down arrows like in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Option + up or down arrow, the list of inspector shortcut can be found here. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/KeyboardShortcuts/KeyboardShortcuts.html

Comment: Thanks for that.  They didn't have this feature when I posted, perhaps they added it in a recent update?

Answer (score 0):

You can now use just the up/down keys by themselves, without holding ⌥. Introduced in Safari Technology Preview 43, this will be making its way to the main build of Safari in the near future.

> - Enabled up and down arrows to modify CSS number values in the redesigned styles sidebar

https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/

Holding ⌥ now steps only by 0.1.

> Up key increments a number, Down key decrements it.
>
> Holding modifier keys changes the step value:
>
> - Option modifies the value by 0.1
> - Shift modifies the value by 10
> - Command modifies the value by 100

https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/223336/webkit/